# MYSQL Group By Date Performance Query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I'm currently writing a query that will run multiple times on a MYISAM table in a MySQL DB.

The query takes a lot (could be anything upto 100,000+) of rows and gets monthly totals. The SQL I'm currently using is

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ct_cdatetime, "%m-%Y") AS Month, SUM(ct_total), SUM(ct_charge)
FROM client_transaction
WHERE (...omitted for this example...)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(ct_cdatetime, "%m-%Y") ORDER BY ct_cdatetime ASC
```

I'm aware of the performance issue of forcing MySQL to cast the date to a string. Would it be quicker and / or better practice to

- 1) Leave it as is
- 2) Select all the rows and group them in PHP in an
  array.
- 3) Have a month-year int field in the database and update this
  when I add the row (e.g. 714 for July 2014)?

Comment: Store your month_year information in a separate column and set an index on it (if this is an often used or time critical query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question of which is fastest is simple:  try both and measure.

The performance on the SQL side is not really affected by the date conversion.  It is determined by the `group by`, and in particular, the sorting for the ordering.

I am skeptical that transferring the data and doing the work on the application side would be faster.  In particular, you have to transfer a large (ish) amount of data from the database to the application.  Then, you have to replicate the work in the application that would be done in the database.

However, the in-memory algorithms on the application side can be faster than the more generic algorithms on the database-side.  It is possible that doing the work on the application side could be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The following query is faster because it just extracts the components of a date instead of creating a formatted text:

```
SELECT YEAR(dtfield), MONTH(dtfield), COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY YEAR(dtfield), MONTH(dtfield);
```

Please keep in mind that MySQL cannot use any index optimization for the `GROUP BY` criteria when using functions. If you have a big table and need this computations often create separate indexed columns for them (as [noticed by hellcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598396/mysql-group-by-date-performance-query#comment38111215_24598396)).